# Can multi threads access same weak_ptr object C++

Tags: c++, multithreading

So I have this class:

```
class Test
{
    ...
    std::weak_ptr<W> m_w;
    std::thread t1;
    std::thread t2;
public:
    Test (const std::shared_ptr<W> w);
    void t1Task();
    void t2Task();
    ...
}
```

In its constructor, pretty regular, they are initialized:

```
...
m_w(w),
...
t1 = std::thread (&Test::t1Task, this);
t2 = std::thread (&Test::t2Task, this);
```

So here comes my question, can I use `lock()` in these 2 task functions considering they start at the same time like I do in the code below? If I can't, what can I do since I have to get a `shared_ptr` to `w` object in both threads?

```
    void Test::t1Task ( )
    {
        std::shared_ptr<W> wPtr = m_w.lock();   // 1st line of this func
        while(/*some condition*/)
        {
             // going to use wPtr in this while loop
        }
    }

    void Test::t2Task()
    {
        std::shared_ptr<W> wPtr = m_w.lock();   // 1st line of this func
        while(/*some condition*/)
        {
             // going to use wPtr in this while loop
        }
    }
```

Comment: As long as your uses are read_only, it should be ok, but if not, this is why C++20 adds `std::atomic_weak_ptr`...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no issue calling `lock`.  `lock` isn't like `lock` on a mutex where it blocks all other threads.  What it does do is effectively *lock* you into the ownership of the pointer if there is still a valid `shared_ptr` some where in your code at that time.

That means the only thing you need to do is check if `wPtr` is not equal to `nullptr` before you use it since `lock` could return a null `shared_ptr`.

---

Do note that this does not provide any thread safety guarantee about the object pointed to by the pointer.  You still have to make sure you access that in a thread safe manner.  Without knowing what you are doing I can't say if your loops are actualy safe.

Comment: Thank you. Sounds like I need to check if it's `nullptr` for every iteration of the while loop. Is it better for me to put `lock()` and check `nullptr` together in the while loop?

Comment: Did you forget about the threads? Because I guess he wants to use the pointer in a thread safe manner

Comment: @Henry You only need to check once.  It can't change to `nuillptr` while you are holding the `shared_ptr`.  You just need to make sure `lock` did not return `nullptr`.

Comment: Note that even though the shared_ptr itself will work across threads, that does not mean the object to which it points is thread safe -- that still has to be programmed in.

Comment: @MikevanDyke Good point, I was only looking at the safety of `lock`.  I've added to the answer.

Comment: @NathanOliver but what if I want to continuously attempt to acquire a `sharer_ptr` out of the `weak_ptr` when it returns `nullptr` in the first place? Is it even a good practice? (btw thank Mike and Eljay for pointing threading thing out)

Comment: @Henry You don't need to worry about both threads doing it at the same time since `lock` is thread safe.  If `lock` does return `nullptr`, then there is no need to try again as it will never return anything else but `nullptr` since there is no valid object anymore.